# Does "No screenshots any more from your phone" sound rude?

Tags: meaning, politeness

Could native speakers tell the first expression of meaning "No screenshots any more from your phone" Does it sound rude?

Comment: A more grammatical sentence would be: "No more screenshots from cells/cell phones/mobiles" but it does sound rather like an order than a request. When you say "screenshot" do you mean *photo*? If you wish to make a request then you could say: "Please refrain from taking any photos" OR "We kindly request that the public  does not take any photos" OR more simply, "Photos are forbidden". I think you should add a little more context. The possibilities are limitless.

Comment: Are you talking about sending a screenshot of an opened file on a smartphone instead of the file itself or a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional context would be helpful in this case, as is the case with the majority of spoken English.

However, in my opinion, the phrase [note: *Frase* is the Scottish variant of *Phrase*], would not likely be taken as rude, due to its broken English. That is, the broken English signals an incomplete understanding of the English language and social constructs to a native English speaker, who would in turn, be more understanding of error and less likely to take such as rude.

However, it is important to also not that verbal tone can throw this off, as certain (more guttural) accents can sound as angry or otherwise annoyed to the native English speaker.

If you are looking for the most polite version of your phrase,

> Please don't take any more screenshots from your phone [, formal title (ex. sir, ma'am)]

would be my choice.

Original Question, Rephrased:

> #### Inquiry into Phrase Meaning, and Perceived Rudeness
>
> Could native speakers please tell me their first impression of the phrase: "No screenshots any more from your phone."
>
> Does the phrase sound rude?

Notes: *expression* ~> *impression*, *frase* ~> *phrase*

I hope this helps you on your way to mastering the ridiculous language of English.